# Calendar API (Google Apps Script) Project not found and cannot be used for API calls

Tags: api, google-apps-script, calendar

I am using Google Apps Scripts following [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/apps-script) tutorial.

When I execute the code I get the following error:

> Project 719340009941 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If
>   it is recently created, enable Calendar API

I went to Resources -> Advanced Google Services and I enabled Calendar. Then I clicked on the [link of Cloud Platform project](https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager). I could not directly search for calendar API, I had to create a project first (which I called Calendar). I searched for Calendar API and enabled it.

When I am on the calendar API page it tells me: **API enabled**. I don´t understand why the script gives me the error.

If I visit the project link (which the error provides) I get the following error

> The API "calendar.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it

Comment: Google Apps Script has a built-in Calendar API, via `CalendarApp` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/ This version of the Google Calendar API does not require the "Advanced Service" configuration, and does have some different syntax than the public REST API.

Comment: But shouldn't it just work like the quickstart tells me?

Comment: When you create an apps script project, it automatically creates a corresponding cloud console project. You should not have needed to create one for it. That said, if you are in a G Suite domain, this automatic project creation may have been disabled / disallowed. You would then need to associate your given apps script project with your cloud console project. This process is described at length in Apps Script documentation.

Comment: `CalendarApp` is limited in its functionality. While it's true you might be able to accomplish your task with `CalendarApp`, you might need extended functionality in some cases which you would enable as indicated in the question. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error, and don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about the different API versions or what a G suite domain is, but if it helps anyone else I resolved this by going to the URL below and hitting the enable button:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/calendar-json.googleapis.com